# why i cant display in web view facebook page login?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

im trying implement a button to login with facebook in my app from xamarin forms , first im doing  now im doing my code in c# Another error that is not debugging you is that it is not bringing me the token, perhaps that is why it is not allowing me to show the login page
[image]

```
private string ClientId = "12345678910";
 private void LogearseFb_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var ApiRequest = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
           + ClientId + "&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        VistaFacebook.Source = ApiRequest;
        VistaFacebook.HeightRequest = 2;

        VistaFacebook.Navigated += VistaFacebook_Navigated;

    }

    private async void VistaFacebook_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var accessToken = extraerurlToken(e.Url);

        if (accessToken != "")
        {
            await GetFacebookProfileAsync(accessToken);
        }
    } 

    public async Task GetFacebookProfileAsync(string accesToken)
    {
        
        var requestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/" + "?fields=name,picture,cover,age_range,devices,email,is_verified"
            + "&access_token=" + accesToken;

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var userJson = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);

    }





    private  string extraerurlToken(string url)
    {
        string scheme = "Facebook";
        if(url.Contains("access_token") && url.Contains("&expires_in="))
        {
            var at = url.Replace("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token={accessToken}", "");

            if (scheme.Equals("Apple")
            && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS
            && DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13)
            {
                // Use Native Apple Sign In API's
                at = url.Replace("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token={accessToken}","");
            }
            var accessToken = at.Remove(at.IndexOf("&expires_in="));
            return accessToken;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: is the image you posted an error message?  What does it say in English?  Or what specific error or exception are you getting?

Comment: ok look , in this image i accept the embedded browser

Comment: *"it is not bringing me the token"* - extraerurlToken does not find a token in url? Is it returning empty string?